# How can the average response time remain more or less constant if I keep increasing the number of threads?

Tags: http, tcp, jmeter, client-server, performance-testing

I have a simple stress test scenario which runs for 2 hours. I have configured 3000 threads to be ramped-up over the whole duration of the test.
It's just one HTTPS POST request repeated multiple times with changing json body data on each request. The client is on one system and the server is on another system. I am just calling an API with some input data and that API looks up data in a file and responds back with whatever it is hardcoded to respond with.

How is it possible that although I keep increasing the number of threads as time goes by, the load on the system does not increase proportionally?

I am asking this because a few days ago when doing this test, the average response time was increasing proportionally with my increase in threads (virtual users). Now when doing the same test, this increase does not happen anymore - that is why now I am guessing that the devs have put some maximum TPS limitation.

This is the Response Times Over Time result:
[image]

This is the Total TPS:
[image]

Active Threads Over Time result:
[image]

Bytes Throughput Over Time:
[image]

Can someone please help me understand how this is possible? There are no error codes.

It seems that the server is somehow limiting the client, but I don't understand through which mechanism and I don't know which jmeter result graph would show me a clearer evidence of this.
I would appreciate if someone could help me understand.

Comment: It is unclear for me how your test setup looks like (client and server on same system, different systems, what does the server even do on each request ...) but I would suggest that the server is not what is limiting the performance. Instead there are more or less constant latencies for each request which are not caused by the server but by the setup and kind of tests. For example a HTTP requests needs several round-trips from start to finish, more so if each request is done in a new TCP connection and even more with TLS.  Such latencies limit the performance, no matter how fast the server is.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It's just one HTTPS POST request repeated multiple times with changing json body data on each request. The client is on one system and the server is on another system. Regardless, I am just calling an API. The reason I am asking this is that a few days ago when doing this test, the average response time was increasing proportionally with my increase in threads (virtual users). Now when doing the same test, this increase does not happen anymore, that is why now I am guessing that the devs put some maximum TPS limitation...

Comment: This kind of context (what it does, how it performed last time - but please with actual numbers) should be part of the question and not be buried in a comment. Also, "calling an API" can mean to just echo back the data, do expensive database backups, contact other systems to collect data ... - which all affects the performance in a different way. Without these crucial information one could only wildly speculate what the limit might here.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question as per your suggestion. You can see numbers in the pictures. I don't have data from the previous runs. Let me know if you think that I can provide any other info. Some speculations could also help me, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing results from different test executions so we cannot properly correlate them, i.e. response times start from `23:15` and 2 other charts end at `23:01`.

In general well-behaved system's throughput should increase proportionally to the increased load. If it doesn't happen - there should be an explanation for this, i.e.

0. Response time increases, try looking at response times for the duration between `22:23` and `23:01`
1. JMeter cannot send the requests fast enough, make sure to follow JMeter Best Practices and to monitor your load generators resources like CPU, RAM, etc. using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
2. Application cannot respond fast enough due to configuration or implementation limitation, check what's going on under the hood of your API call using [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) or [Profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) tool
3. The fact that JMeter doesn't report errors doesn't necessarily mean that there are no errors, your application may respond with [HTTP Status Code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) but the body contains the error details so it makes sense to look at i.e. [Bytes Throughput Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/BytesThroughput/) chart to see if the volume of transmitted data grows as the users arrive. You can also consider adding [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to your requests to ensure that your test is doing what it's supposed to be doing

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. Regarding the graphs, It was a mistake from my side, sorry. I have updated the question content with results from the same execution now. Now all graphs start at 23:15. I will definitely check out the links which you have provided. As always, your observations and responses are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be caused by the client throttling the actual number of threads been executed. In other words, the threads could be queuing at the load-generator. See Dr. Gunter [How to Get Unbelievable Load Test Results](https://www.helpsystems.com/resources/guides/how-get-unbelievable-load-test-results), specifically the **4.4 Threads That Throttle** section for a detailed explanation. The paper shows a method using Little's Law to estimate the actual number of threads been executed.